# Fill SVG on parent div hover (no JS)

Tags: html, css, svg

I have 2 SVG paths and I would like them to change fill color when users rollover their parents did. I can get the hover working but only when users hover on the svg. I know it is easy with JS but I would prefer to stick with CSS.

```
<div class="button">
   <svg width="100px" height="100px">
       <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" style="stroke: black;"/>
   </svg>
</div>

<div class="button">
   <svg width="100px" height="100px">
       <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="20" style="stroke: black;"/>
   </svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
    background-color:gray;
    margin-bottom: 20px ;
}

svg{
    fill:green;
}

svg:hover{
    fill:blue;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/69g7K/

Comment: Here is an example of what I have - http://jsfiddle.net/69g7K/

Answer (score 5):

We can do this, by using `parent:hover` as selector to vary the CSS attributes of `child1` and `child2` which are within their respective parents..

Use the following for the CSS :

```
.button:hover .svg1{
    fill:blue;
}

.button:hover .svg2{
    fill:yellow;
}
```

Demo : [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7wnxdykp/)

Comment: This came up in the Low Quality Posts queue because of the lack of explanation. Adding an explanation of the code helps this user, and other users who find this answer via search.

Comment: This is exactly what resolved my issue. I was having a problem changing the fill when clicking on the parent div. .parent:active .child-icon {fill: white;} did the trick.

Comment: This only works if you know beforehand whether your SVG uses stroke or fill with the desired color.

Answer (score 1):

here is a trick if you have a more complex svg element, for instance if you have multiple paths, do the following:

```
<div class="your-class">
  <svg [svg content...]
    <path ...>
    <path ...>
    <path ...>
</div>
```

use css to look for paths not only something inside a specific path:

```
.your-class{
/* code without rover */
transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.your-class:hover path{
stroke: #C4C4C4; /* use stroke to color svg lines*/ 
/* use fill to color the inside */
```

also (maybe worth mentioning) if you your div to be only around the svg you can use the `width: fit-content;` for your div

hope it helps you out

Answer (score 0):

```
 svg {
        fill: #444;
    }​
```

just add a class to each SVG and use the css above something like this:

```
svg.svg1:hover {
            fill: #666;
        }​


svg.svg2:hover {
            fill: #666;
        }​
```

remove  `style="fill: yellow"` for example from each SVG path otherweise it will overwrite your css

```
   <svg class=svg1 width=150px height=150px>
       <circle cx=64 cy=64 r=20>
   </svg>


   <svg class=svg2 width=150px height=150px>
       <circle cx=64 cy=64 r=20>
   </svg>
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/GwWk5/

```
svg {
    fill: red;
}

svg.svg1:hover {
    fill: blue;
}
svg.svg2:hover {
    fill: green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I still don't know how to make the svg change fill on the parent div hover though.http://jsfiddle.net/69g7K/1/

Comment: if you want your SVG to change on the parent div hover just use currentcolor and color like this http://jsfiddle.net/69g7K/2/

Comment: you may be correct but i think it is up to user2793640 to tell us what he wants :-)

Comment: Thank you both so much. Vals - that is what I was trying to do. I never realized that you had to select the svg that way. Mission accomplished!